# templates page not showing on gutenberg editor

Tags: templates, block-editor

Have install the latest wordpress 6.1.1 and want to use a template using the gutenberg theme editor, using the twenty-twenty-three theme for example. Then when I go to edit page, the template page  option to apply the theme isn't there, have try it out with 7 or 10 different themes and still not showing, how can I apply a template to a page this way

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The template option has been moved here in WordPress 6.1:

[image]

Comment: awesome, after a few hours, was here all the time. Thanks